# Number of Solutions in counting problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find the number of solutions to the equation a + b + c + d = 50 if 
each variable is:

(a) a non-negative integer

(b) a positive integer

(c) an odd positive integer

(d) an integer between 4 and 10 (inclusive)

Question like this but I would like to understand the logic of the solution, so just can give me a hint or solution way.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/756516/73324

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) This is the stars and bars problem. So we have $\binom{50 + 4 - 1}{50}$.

(b) Since each variable can be positive, it is at least $1$. So we subtract $50 - 4(1) = 46$. This allows us to reduce to case (a), except we use $46$ instead of $50$: $\binom{46 + 4 - 1}{46}$.

(c) Odd numbers are of the form $2x + 1$. So we again subtract $1$ from $50$ for each variable, leaving us with $2x_{1} + 2x_{2} + 2x_{3} + 2x_{4} = 46$. We then divide out by $2$ to get $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} = 23$. We now reduce to case (a): $\binom{23 + 4 - 1}{23}$.

(d) Let's start out by subtracting $4$ from $50$ for each variable, so each variable is between $0-6$, and we are finding the sum of $34$. I would set this one up with a generating function, since we have an inclusion-exclusion argument:

$f_{i}(x) = (1 + x + x^{2} + x^{3} + ... + x^{6}) = \dfrac{1-x^{7}}{1-x}$.

So that's the generating function for a single variable. We raise it to the fourth, since we have four variables with the same constraint: $f(x) = (\dfrac{1-x^{7}}{1-x})^{4}$.

I then expand out the numerator and denominator using binomial coefficients:

$(1-x^{7})^{4} = (1 - 4x^{7} + 6x^{14} - 4x^{21} + x^{28})$

$(\frac{1}{1-x})^{4} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \binom{i + 4 - 1}{i} x^{i}$.

We foil them and take the coefficients of the $x^{34}$ terms, which gives us $\binom{34 + 4 - 1}{34} - 4\binom{27 + 4 - 1}{27} + 6\binom{20 + 4 - 1}{20} - 4\binom{13 + 4 - 1}{13} + \binom{6 + 4 - 1}{6}$.